# How to make a redux dispatch action async using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make redux dispatch action async using redux toolkit. I'm doing this to handle UI freeze caused due to redux state update (using `setFilterInfo` reducer).

While searching for a way to do it, I came across createAsyncThunk. However, all the examples showed its usage in respect of fetching data. I ended up with the following code. The problem is still not solved, UI is still freezing while updating the redux state.

```
// This is the Thunk
export const filterInfoSetterThunk = createAsyncThunk(
"screenSlice/setFilterInfo",
async (filter, thunkAPI) =\> {
return filter;
}
);


// Slice 
const screenSlice = createSlice({
  name: "screenSlice",

  initialState: {
    filter_info: []
  },
  reducers: {
    
    setFilterInfo(state, action) {
      state.filter_info = action.payload.filter_info;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(filterInfoSetterThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log("Inside extra reducer", action.payload.filter_info);
      state.filter_info = action.payload.filter_info;
    });
  },
});
```

```
// calling filterInfoSetterThunk inside a function 

updateFilterInfoInReduxStore = async (data) => {
   await filterInfoSetterThunk({filter_info: data})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling  `await filterInfoSetterThunk({filter_info: data})` **incorrectly** here.

**Instead** of this `dispatch(filterInfoSetterThunk({filter_info: data}))`

Comment: I've imported the thunk and created a dispatch dictionary like this  ```const dispatch = {
  setScreenerQueryResponse,
  setSelectedMetrics,
  setScreenerFilter,
  setFilterInfo,
  filterInfoSetterThunk,
};``` and then I'm passing this dictionary dictionary as a param to connect like this ```export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch)(CategoricalFilter)```